# Formula of number of pairs of consecutive quadratic residues and non-residues modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a question regarding the formula involving the number of pairs of consecutive quadratic residues and non-residues. Let $p$ be an odd prime. Denote $(RR)$ to be the number of pairs $(n,n+1)$ in the set $1,2,3,⋯,p−1$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ are both quadratic residues modulo $p$, and $(RN)$ the number of pairs when $n$ is a quadratic residue and $n+1$ is a quadratic non-residue. Such formula is given by
\begin{equation}
(RR)+(RN)=\dfrac{1}{2}\Big[p−2−(−1)^\frac{p−1}{2}\Big].
\end{equation} I know that that I have to consider the cases when $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and when $p\equiv 3 \pmod 4$ as mentioned in the exercise's hint, but I don't know how to proceed and why I have to consider these two particular cases. Any help or hint that you can give me will be truly appreciated.